# From continuous Fourier transform to discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying to derive the formula from continuous Fourier transform to discrete Fourier transform, however, I encountered a small problem. My derivations are the following.

For a periodic function $f(x)=f(x+a)$, the continuous Fourier transform read
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{a}x}\\
c_n &= \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a dx e^{-i\frac{2\pi n}{a}x}f(x)
\end{align}
In order to get the discrete Fourier tranform, I discretize the $x$-axis into $N$ pieces, and for the sampling $x$-points $x_j = \frac{a}{N}j$, they satisfy $f_j = f_{j+N}$, where I defined $f_j\equiv f(x_j)$.
Therefore the first equation becomes
\begin{equation}
f_j = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{a}x_j} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{N}j}
\end{equation}
and the second equation becomes
\begin{equation}
c_n = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \frac{a}{N} e^{-i\frac{2\pi n}{a} j\frac{a}{N}} f_j = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{-i\frac{2\pi n}{N}j} f_j
\end{equation}

My question comes from in the third equation, the n-summation runs from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ which differs from the standard DFT that from $0$ to $N-1$. What's wrong with my derivation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $e^{\frac{2\pi (N-j)}{N}} = e^{-\frac{2\pi j}{N}}$. Rewrite your summation.

Comment: Sorry, could you give more details? I know that $e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{N}j}$ is a periodic function with respect to $n$. However, if I restrict the summation in the third equation from $0$ to $N-1$, an infinite pre-factor comes out.

Comment: Usually, what you call continuous Fourier transform is called Fourier series, since the Fourier transform is the case of non-periodic functions.

Comment: The way how it was called is not important, but what's wrong with my derivation?